# What is the better way to return data from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

i am building a javascript game at the moment, and have certain parts of the game coded in separate files e.g. main.js for the loop and initializations etc and then i have level, player, collisions files.

The game files (level,player,collisions) are set up like so:

```
function Level(){

  this.draw_level = function(){

  }
}
```

and then called from my main file like this:

```
var level = new Level();
level.draw_level();
```

The problem i am having is returning information from the nested functions. Here is the code i am referring to:

```
function Level (){

//other functions

 this.collisionLayer = function(layer){
    if(!layer.properties && !layer.properties.collision){return;}
    var t = this,
        row = [];
    t.solids = [];
    layer.data.forEach(function(idx, i) {
        if (i % layer.width === 0 && i) {
            t.solids.push(row);
            row = [];
        }
        row.push(idx);
    });
    t.solids.push(row);

}
}
```

and is called from my main file like this:

```
var collisions =  level.collisionLayer(layers)
```

What i would like to do is return the t.solids array so i can utilize the information stored in it in the main JS file.

I have tried

```
return t;
```

but i get the function highlighted with the error:

```
function has inconsistent return points
```

SO my question is:

What is the better way to return information in a situation like mine? Store in a global variable? or some other way?

AND what does the error above mean? Would be good to know for future reference.

Thanks

Comment: Store `t` directly in the `level` function rather than in a child scope, then return it from the level function and not the child scope.

Comment: You're not actually getting an error. Your IDE is simply telling you that you're only returning inside the scope of that if () statement, and that it's expecting returns from all scopes (for consistency).

Comment: so make t a variable of level then at the bottom of the script return t? WOuld this work if i have other functions withing the same file that are called at a totally different time, or will it interfere with the other functions?

Comment: @derek i was trying to return outside both the loops you can see and still got the message, what does this mean? thanks

Comment: @derek, also if i was to run this code, theoretically i wouldnt get an error because it is just my ide warning me?

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: t just points to the level object. You can just get the array from level.solids.

Comment: Tom, you are correct, if you run it it should still work without throwing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your inputs guys.
As Parthik Gosar said, i can just access the solids array using level.solids!
Thanks again